# Using Apache POI how to read a specific excel column

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm having a problem in excel while using Apache POI. I can read across rows, but sometimes I'm in a situation where I would like to read a particular column only.

So is it possible to read any particular column like only the 'A' column only or the column 'C' only.

I'm using the **Java** language for this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

heikkim is right, here is some sample code adapted from some code I have:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
...
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowIndex++) {
  row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
  if (row != null) {
    Cell cell = row.getCell(colIndex);
    if (cell != null) {
      // Found column and there is value in the cell.
      cellValueMaybeNull = cell.getStringCellValue();
      // Do something with the cellValueMaybeNull here ...
      // break; ???
    }
  }
}
```

For the `colCount` use something like `row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells()`

Comment: Thank you Christophe .. but I have one doubt .. I have in col1 a 4 cells filled but in col3 8 cells filled so when I run the code it will run 8 time but I only what 4 in col1 and I just want the num of filled cells in a particular column because i'm feeding this count and the data to the input of my test .. please help .. once again thanks for your time and for the code ...

Comment: Just skip the rows with now value for the cell?

Comment: I added a `break`, it is a great classic to forget it in that case :)

Comment: You could've directly used `cell = row.getCell(theColIndexYouWant);` instead of using a loop.

Comment: @backslashN This was in 2012, I quickly adapted some of my code for the need of the question but you are right, I updated the code as this is more efficient

Answer (score 6):

```
  Sheet sheet  = workBook.getSheetAt(0); // Get Your Sheet.

  for (Row row : sheet) { // For each Row.
      Cell cell = row.getCell(0); // Get the Cell at the Index / Column you want.
  }
```

My solution, a bit simpler code wise.

Comment: You seem to be iterating over all the columns, then ignoring the columns you don't want. Wouldn't it be much simpler to only fetch the cell of interest off a given row?

Comment: Yes that is what it's doing. I wouldn't suggest this for large files as it's not efficient although for small files it'll be fine. It does keep it simpler code wise / easier to maintain would you not agree?

Comment: Actually you where right that was very bad. I've updated it with the more obvious choice.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, from your question, you just simply want to read a particular column. So, while iterating over a row and then on its cells, your can simply check the index of the column.

```
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = mySheet.iterator(); // Traversing over each row of XLSX file
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next(); // For each row, iterate through each columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                println "column index"+cell.getColumnIndex()//You will have your columns fixed in Excel file
                if(cell.getColumnIndex()==3)//for example of c
                {
                print "done"            
                }
          }
     }
```

I am using POI 3.12-- 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.12'
Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: If you only care about one column, why not fetch only that cell? Why iterate over all cells in a row until you find it?

Comment: Actually yes, I hope you are referring to "CellReference" class ?

Comment: Nope, just use `row.getCell(columnNumber)` !

Answer (score 2):

You could just loop the rows and read the same cell from each row (doesn't this comprise a column?).

Comment: Thank you Brian for the reply .. yes but in the case where col1 has 4 cell filled while col5 has 6 cell filled at that time i'm confused because i'm feeding this data to my test input values . so can u tell me how to find the num of cell filled in a column ... please help

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.text.*;

public class XSLXReader {
    static DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#####0");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileWriter fostream;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        String strOutputPath = "H:\\BLR_Team\\Kavitha\\Excel-to-xml\\";
        String strFilePrefix = "Master_5.2-B";

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("H:\\BLR_Team\\Kavitha\\Excel-to-xml\\Stack-up 20L pure storage 11-0039-01 ISU_USA-A 1-30-17-Rev_exm.xls"));
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
           // Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(0);
            Sheet sheet =null;
            Integer noOfSheets= wb.getNumberOfSheets();

            for(int i=0;i<noOfSheets;i++){
                sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);
                System.out.println("Sheet : "+i + " " + sheet.getSheetName());
                System.out.println("Sheet : "+i + " " + sheet.getFirstRowNum());
                System.out.println("Sheet : "+i + " " + sheet.getLastRowNum());

            //Column 29
            fostream = new FileWriter(strOutputPath + "\\" + strFilePrefix+i+ ".xml");
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(fostream));

            out.println("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
            out.println("<Bin-code>");

            boolean firstRow = true;
            for (Row row : sheet) {
                if (firstRow == true) {
                    firstRow = false;
                    continue;
                }
                out.println("\t<DCT>");
                out.println(formatElement("\t\t", "ID", formatCell(row.getCell(0))));
                out.println(formatElement("\t\t", "Table_name", formatCell(row.getCell(1))));
                out.println(formatElement("\t\t", "isProddaten", formatCell(row.getCell(2))));
                out.println(formatElement("\t\t", "isR3P01Data", formatCell(row.getCell(3))));

                out.println(formatElement("\t\t", "LayerNo", formatCell(row.getCell(29))));
                out.println("\t</DCT>");
            }
            CellReference ref = new CellReference("A13");
          Row r = sheet.getRow(ref.getRow());
          if (r != null) {
             Cell c = r.getCell(ref.getCol());
           System.out.println(c.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
          }

            for (Row row : sheet) {
                  for (Cell cell : row) {

                      CellReference cellRef = new CellReference(row.getRowNum(), cell.getColumnIndex());


                      switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                          System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                          break;
                      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                          if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                              System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
                          } else {
                              System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                          }
                          break;
                      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                          System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                          break;
                      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                          System.out.println(cell.getCellFormula());
                          break;
                      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                          System.out.println();
                          break;
                      default:
                          System.out.println();
                  }
                  }

            }
            out.write("</Bin-code>");
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String formatCell(Cell cell)
    {
        if (cell == null) {
            return "";
        }
        switch(cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                return "";
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                return Boolean.toString(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                return "*error*";
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                return XSLXReader.df.format(cell.getNumericCellValue());
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                return cell.getStringCellValue();
            default:
                return "<unknown value>";
        }
    }

    private static String formatElement(String prefix, String tag, String value) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(prefix);
        sb.append("<");
        sb.append(tag);
        if (value != null && value.length() > 0) {
            sb.append(">");
            sb.append(value);
            sb.append("</");
            sb.append(tag);
            sb.append(">");
        } else {
            sb.append("/>");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

This code does 3 things:

1. Excel to XML file generation.    Eng. Name  Dong Kim
2. Prints the content of a particular cell : A13
3. Also print the excel content into normal text format. Jars to be imported: poi-3.9.jar,poi-ooxml-3.9.jar,poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar,xbea‌​n-2.3.0.jar,xmlbeans‌​-xmlpublic-2.4.0.jar‌​,dom4j-1.5.jar

Comment: You should put the explanation in your answer not in the comments.

Comment: @Neil Patrao: Thanks for moving the comments to explanation section.

Comment: @Kavithayadav I came to this thread, your codes works at my end. but i need to know how to define the codes to read particular sheet....could u advise

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to read the excel data by column.

```
public ArrayList<String> extractExcelContentByColumnIndex(int columnIndex){
        ArrayList<String> columndata = null;
        try {
            File f = new File("sample.xlsx")
            FileInputStream ios = new FileInputStream(f);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(ios);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            columndata = new ArrayList<>();

            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    if(row.getRowNum() > 0){ //To filter column headings
                        if(cell.getColumnIndex() == columnIndex){// To match column index
                            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                columndata.add(cell.getNumericCellValue()+"");
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                columndata.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ios.close();
            System.out.println(columndata);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return columndata;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware, that iterating through the columns using row cell iterator ( `Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();`) may lead to silent skipping columns. I have just encountered a document that was exposing such behaviour.

Iterating using indexes in a for loop and using `row.getCell(i)` was not skipping columns and was returning values at the correct column indexes.