# how to move the active cell to the top left cell in the range apache poi using XSSFWorkbook?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to migrate the java excel code from JBook to XSSFWorkbook. Am not getting exact methods that are used in JBook. Some of them are:

```
JBook.setSelection(int row, int col, int row, int col);
JBook.setSelection(JBook.getDefinedName("some String"));
```

The first method explains moving the active cell to the top left cell in the range.
Is there any way to get the rowindex and column index from XSSFWorkbook object?

Comment: Take look at this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857469/using-apache-poi-how-to-read-a-specific-excel-column

Answer (score 1):

You can't set active cell via workbook object.
Possible options:

- if you have cell object you can mark it as active: `cell.setAsActiveCell();`
- if you work with `XSSFSheet` and want to set multiple cell selection: `xssfSheet.setActiveCell(reference)` (works with `xmlbeans 2.6.0`, not `2.3.0`)

Reference can be set as a string: `"A1:A2"` or using `CellReference` class:

```
String reference = new CellReference(rowNum, colNum).formatAsString()
```

> Is there any way to get the rowindex and column index from XSSFWorkbook object?

You can get index from the cell:

```
cell.getColumnIndex()
cell.getRowIndex()
```

I don't know what is `JBook.getDefinedName("some String")` but if it works with named ranges, check POI user guide: [Named Ranges and Named Cells](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NamedRanges).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this way

```
         HSSFWorkbook book1 = new HSSFWorkbook();
         HSSFSheet sheet = book1.getSheet("sheetName");
         int rowIndex=sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;//
         int columnIndex = sheet.getRow(sheet.getLastRowNum()).getPhysicalNumberOfCells()
```

Comment: and what would be the methods for setselection(). which i mentioned in question?

Comment: what is  `Jbook` pckage and which library it is ?

Comment: it is of com.f1j.swing.JBook.

Comment: its hard to find api of that `com.f1j.swing.JBook` What exactly that `setSelection()` method will do ?

Comment: setSelection(int row1, int col1, int row2, int col2)
          Selects the specified range and moves the active cell to the top left cell in the range.
setSelection(java.lang.String selectionFormula)
          Selects the range represented by the formula, specified in U.S.

Comment: That means it will merge with active cell and specified cell location by the parameters ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98077/discussion-between-swetha-and-babel).