# Java - Apache POI read XSSF File at specific cell

Tags: java, apache-poi

How can i get a specific cell value from my excel xlsx sheet ?
For example i want to get all values from the cell 6 and 8.
Here's what i done -  i get the whole row

```
    public void readExcelFile() {

    try {
        InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("D:\\20161111_Gesamtliste_aller_Anschreiben.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);

        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFRow row;
        XSSFCell cell;
        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
        int read = 0;

        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            read++;
            row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();

            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();

                if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + " ");
                } else if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + " ");
                } else {
                }
            }
            System.out.println();

        }

        System.out.println(read);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12857969/6565719) helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Row row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
    int rowcellnum = row.getLastCellNum();
    for (int cn = 0; cn < rowcellnum; cn++) {
        String cellVal = "";
        Cell cell = row.getCell(cn);
        if (cell == null) {
            //HANDLE NULL
        }
        if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + " ");
        } else if (cell.getCellType() ==  XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + " ");
        } else {
        }
    }
```

Based on index i.e cn you can access specific cell.