# Java: Read specific columns too memory consuming

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to read a large (50000 row and 20 columns) excel file using Apache POI library. There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857469/using-apache-poi-how-to-read-a-specific-excel-column) that asks exactly the same thing. My attempted approach is as follows:

```
public static ArrayList<Double> readColumn(String excelFile,String sheetName, int columnNumber)
        {
            ArrayList<Double> excelData = new ArrayList<>();
            XSSFWorkbook  workbook = null;
            try
            {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
            for (int i = 0; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++)
            {
                Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
                if (row != null) {
                    Cell cell = row.getCell(columnNumber);
                    if (cell != null)
                    {
                        // Skip cellls that are not numericals
                        if (cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC)
                        {
                            excelData.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return excelData;
        }
```

Unfortunately, while this method seems to work when accessing a low index column number (e.g. columnNumber =1), I get an OutOfMemoryError exception for a large columnNumber. The file itself is not too large to make my computer run out memory. I can achieve the same outcome in Python with very little memory requirements.Is there a better way to solve this? Or, is there any Java library that would allow me to do that?

Comment: You can try using https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader . I am on mobile so I cannot find the updated version. Also recommend increasing heap size for large file reads. POI is notorious for its memory usage.

Comment: @Jeremy thanks a lot! I will look into your suggested library